# Is $f(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$ always monotonically increasing?

Tags: limits, functions

> Is the function $f(x) = \frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$ always monotonically increasing?

As it is bound to $(-1,1)$, I am confused because $f(x)$ reaches a constant value when $x$ approaches infinity. So it can not increase after a certain point.

Comment: $\frac1x$ is monotonically decreasing even though the limit is "a constant value"

Answer (score 4):

Yes,
$f(x) = e^x/(1+e^x)
$
*is* monotonically increasing.

To see this without calculus,
write it as
$\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}
=\frac{1+e^x-1}{1+e^x}
=1-\frac{1}{1+e^x}
$.

Now,
$e^x$ is increasing,
so
$\frac{1}{1+e^x}$
is decreasing,
so
$1-\frac{1}{1+e^x}$
is increasing.

Answer (score 2):

There's no issue with being monotonically increasing towards a constant. Any function with a horizontal asymptote does this. For another example, consider:

$$f(x) = \frac{x}{x+1}$$

Comment: Or consider $\arctan(x)$.